# Ext.tab.Panel and word wrap

Tags: extjs, tabpanel

In `extJS` modern toolkit, there is `Ext.tab.Panel`.
At the item of panel property Title is "SuperPuper tab".
In Phone view, I see title in one line. So " tab" part is not visible - title "too long". Can I wrap Title to two lines in phone view? but in tablet view title can be in one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding below css class:

```
.x-button .x-text-el {
    white-space: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For tabpanel add css class

```
.x-tab .x-inner-el .x-body-el .x-text-el {
 white-space: inherit;
}
```